# Is there a way to add documentation to a Conan package AND make it accessible through the web browser? (Gitlab)

Tags: c++, gitlab, documentation, conan, artifacts

I am using Conan to create C++ artifacts. I am uploading these artifacts to Gitlab's Package Registry.

However, I am also generating documentation of the code with Doxygen (HTML) and I would like to upload somehow this documentation together with the package to Gitlab.

I tried to feature the documentation INSIDE the package but this solution does not satisfy me since the package is compressed and the HTML files would not be accessible though the web browser.

Comment: Please be aware that Gitlab registry doesn't support the Http API v2, that is necessary for Conan 2.0, which is the latest release (and very recommended for Conan 1.X, with revisions enabled, which is also the recommendation)

Comment: Conan 2.0 is bringing the "metadata": https://github.com/conan-io/conan/pull/13918, it is a new mechanism that can store extra files in packages, that are not retrieved by default when the package is used (so not paying for it, as mostly not needed in the client side)